# Xamarin Forms Intellisense for Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms, intellisense

I want to know if an other extension works for Visual Studio to have an Intellisense for xamarin forms

I found a good extension :

http://www.cazzulino.com/enable-xaml-forms-intellisense.html

But as you can see, we have a 404 error...

And this extension not working (I can't see the extension)

http://brianlagunas.com/getting-intellisense-for-xamarin-forms/

Can you help me ?

(I know Resharper but it is not free...)

Comment: If you cannot get Resharper and you want the intellisense then go for Xamarin Studio

Comment: You don't have intellisense for XAML? Did you tried to tweak any settings in VS?

Answer (score 3):

To get the intellisense for xamarin.forms XAML file, you can close the xaml tab in the Editor windows, right click the xaml file and choose ‘Open With…’ and select ‘Source Code (Text) Editor’, then the intellisense works fine as below:
[image]

If the above method works, you can also choose ‘Set as Default’ when you select ‘Open With…’’. You can have a look at [this similar issue](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/64005/intellisense-problem-in-visual-studio) and take care of other tips like reopen all open tabs in VS, restart the VS, clean up the solution and delete the .suo file.

Comment: I have this intellisense, but it is not complete. You have'nt ItemSource for ListView for example...

Comment: @Naografix, have you already open the .xaml file with 'Source Code (Text) Editor’? Since I can found the ItemSource as the screenshot: https://1drv.ms/i/s!Atv5QNuFrncKgmC_tOpviBLpJnBt, do you have the intellisense for 'ItemSource'? If this issue still persists, it is better to provide the detail steps to reproduce your issue from the project type that you create and how do you add the xaml into the project..., I will follow your step to check this issue on my side.

Comment: Just reopening of the VS helped

Answer (score 0):

This two steps worked for me:
1. Delete obj folder ( to remove ...g.cs files)
2. Clean project

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and none of the answers helped me! I looked at the output window and found an error for long path. So I moved the solution to another folder with a short path, and everything worked well.